# Is there any condition where Bigdecimal with MathContext.DECIMAL32 does not provides correct result?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, mathcontext

`System.out.println("Result="+new BigDecimal(((63.19* 15) + (63.37* 5))).divide(new BigDecimal(15 + 5), MathContext.DECIMAL64).doubleValue());`

Result=63.23499999999999

But with `MathContext.DECIMAL32` we are getting correct result, see below:

`System.out.println("Result="+new BigDecimal(((63.19* 15) + (63.37* 5))).divide(new BigDecimal(15 + 5), MathContext.DECIMAL32).doubleValue());`

Result=63.235

Comment: For me, the problem seems to be in `63.19` and `63.37` float decimal points. Have you checked the result of this operations If you create the `BigDecimal`s from `String`s?

Comment: I Know create the BigDecimals from Strings is best practice. but atleast i want 1 situation where Bigdecimal with MathContext.DECIMAL32 does not provides correct result?

Comment: Start by using the class in the right way. I could only say that NO, there's no way MathContext.DECIMAL32 will provide a correct result. In fact, the only way to obtain *wrong* results while using `BigDecimal` is if you use `double` to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here not `BigDecimal`, but the fact that `(63.19* 15) + (63.37* 5)` is not `1264.7` but `1264.6999999999998`, because the former cannot be represented as a `double`.

If you do

```
new BigDecimal("1264.7").divide(new BigDecimal("20"), MathContext.DECIMAL64)
```

instead, you get the desired result.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(1264.7)` won't give you the right answer either.  It has to be `new BigDecimal("1264.7")`, passed in as a `String`.

Comment: @LouisWasserma I've changed my answer, as you are right that you should use the `String` constructor.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was confusing `new BigInteger(double)` with `BigInteger.valueOf(1264.7)` which confusingly does give you `1264.7`.

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf` more-or-less papers over the issues with double representation; use the string constructor if it's at all possible.

Comment: I Know create the BigDecimals from Strings is best practice. but atleast i want 1 situation where Bigdecimal with MathContext.DECIMAL32 does not provides correct result?